# Asp.net core dotnet.exe error -2147450749 (0x80008083)

Tags: c#, .net, asp.net-core, .net-core

I've a problem with the new visual studio 2017 and asp.net core.
When i create a new asp.net core project  I receive this error in console when I launch the application.

```
Il programma '[8004] dotnet.exe' è terminato con il codice -2147450749 (0x80008083).
Il programma '[2288] iexplore.exe' è terminato con il codice -1 (0xffffffff).
Il programma '[8100] iisexpress.exe' è terminato con il codice 0 (0x0).
```

I don't have any idea, I've installed all net core platform and version but it is not working.

Comment: Can you be more specific? what new "project" do you use? how did you install everything?

Comment: HI, thanks for reply, i use new project-> web aspnet core application

Comment: Now works, I've install the aspnet core 1.1.1 x86, how to use the x64?

Comment: Good :) please answer your own question and mark it as "solution"  so others might be helped with it :)

Answer (score 0):

Stefano - Visual Studio is 32 bit only (there is no 64bit version) so in order to keep the bit depth the same - things that work with Visual Studio must be 32bit.